# WSO2 IS: Difference between application-authenticator and carbon-authenticator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When walking through the code of WSO2 identity server 5.x, I can find a samlsso authenticator in application-authenticator and another one in carbon-authenticator.  Same is true for IWA.

What is the difference between these? Which one is used when? Or is one of them obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Authenticators are used to authenticate users to the external apps (service providers) using WSO2 products.

Carbon authenticators are used to authenticate users to the admin console of that particular server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.